# Use ktor to uniformly process network models

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class ResBean<T>(
    @SerialName("code")
    val code: Int = 0,
    @SerialName("data")
    val data: T,
    @SerialName("message")
    val message: String = "",
    @SerialName("ttl")
    val ttl: Int = 0
)
```

When defining an interface, a large amount of nesting is carried out in the generic type, which is poor in readability and takes time and effort. Therefore, I want unified processing of ResBean

```kotlin
   private val customHeaderPlugin =
        createClientPlugin("CustomHeaderPlugin") {
            transformResponseBody { response, content, requestedType ->
                val jsonObject = Json.parseToJsonElement(response.bodyAsText()).jsonObject
                jsonObject["data"]
            }
        }
```

Now in ktor I can only process this far, and what is returned is json instead of an object
http://www.whdreamblog.cn/2017/05/29/%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8GsonConverter%E7%BB%9F%E4%B8%80%E5%A4%84%E7%90%86%E7%BD%91%E7%BB%9Cmodel/